# Django: how to pass captured parameters in the url to extra parameters?

Tags: python, django

I remember reading somewhere that captured parameters in the url can be passed to extra parameters. For example:

```
url(r'^products/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', 
    'someview',
    {parameter: <object_id>},
    name='someview'),
```

In this case, I want to pass `object_id` into the extra parameters. Can I do that? I simply can't remember where I read about this trick. Or maybe I don't remember well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extra parameters are just that: extra. You don't have to "pass in" the parameter in the URL because that's done by default. Extra parameters are for values that should always be passed to the view regardless of what comes from the URL itself.

Comment: Then maybe I remember wrong. I thought I read a trick of passing url captured parameter to extra parameters to format strings something.

Comment: I plough through django documents again and find that redirect_to function can capture parameters in url and pass it to url provided url has some format string in it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/generic-views/?from=olddocs#django-views-generic-simple-redirect-to. But I feel it useless since I won't hardcode url in the urls.py. I guess it's more useful in 1.3 since there's a reverse_lazy starting from this version (I'm still using 1.2).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
url(
    (r'^(?P<base62_id>\w+)$', 'shortener.views.follow'),
}
```

... 
The view can access it as:

```
def follow(request, base62_id):
```

Comment: I know it. But it's not my question.